# How to change string output from basic color to random colors

Tags: assembly, masm

I am new to assembly and am trying to make a program that outputs the user string backwords. I also want to make it so anytime the user types something, it will output the reversed string in random colors. But I have no idea how to do this. Is it possible for someone to do this code for me or tell me where to modify the code? Thank you so much in advance.

```
INCLUDE Irvine32.inc

.data

stringInput byte 50 dup(0)

promptIn byte "Enter the string: ",0

.code

swaping MACRO a,b

XOR a,b

XOR b,a

XOR a,b

ENDM

strlen proc

push ebp

mov ebp, esp

push ebx

mov eax, 0

mov ebx, [ebp+8]

Counter:

cmp byte ptr [ebx + eax], 0

je Done

inc eax

jmp counter

Done:

pop ebx

mov esp, ebp

pop ebp

ret TYPE ebp

strlen endp

strrev proc

Push ebp

MOV ebp, esp

Push eax

Push ebx

Push ecx

Mov ebx, [ebp+8]

Mov ecx, [ebp+8]

push ebx

call strlen

ADD ecx, eax

SHR al,1

count: CMP al,0

JZ finished

MOV ah, byte PTR [ebx]

swaping ah, byte ptr [ecx-1]

MOV BYTE PTR [ebx], ah

INC ebx

DEC ecx

DEC al

JMP count

finished: POP ecx

POP ebx

POP eax

MOV esp, ebp

POP ebp

RET (TYPE ebp)*4

strrev ENDP

main proc

mov eax, 0

mov edx, offset promptIn

call writeString

mov edx, offset stringInput

mov ecx, 51

call readString

push edx

call strrev

call crlf

call writestring

call crlf

exit

main endp

end main
```

Comment: In assembly things like how to display character or pixel, colours, sounds, etc... always depend on the target platform. From the "masm" tag and "Irvine32.inc" I guess you are on MS windows using Irvine library, so why don't you check the API provided by it, what it does allow you to do? http://programming.msjc.edu/asm/help/index.html (for example `SetTextColor` looks promising, in case you want to change text colour). If you would need more freedom, you would probably have to check the Win32 API and call the OS directly and with correct initialization + correct conditions, as required by OS.

Comment: thanks for the help, I figured it out with that website